# Проход пакетов через Nat и роутеры в сети

Tags: java, ip, nat

Реализую мессенджер. Клиент отправляет запрос на сервер, допустим на добавление другого пользователя. Сервер посылает в ответ сообщение.

Второму клиенту, который онлайн сервер, сам инициирует запрос, то есть на клиенте в режиме прослушки есть ServerSocket, который постоянно ждет пакеты.

Вопрос: как он пройдет Nat провайдера? Но это еще пол беды, как он распределит запросы если за одним роутером сидят несколько пользователей данного чата? То есть сервер как, я понимаю, знает айпишник и порт (который у всех пользователей одинаковый) клиента, он посылает туда сообщение о новом друге, Nat поймет, что на этот сервер запрашивал доступ определенный PC (опять же встает вопрос если их несколько и они все в режиме серверсокета ожидают ответ на одном порте за одним роутером, или же даже не за одним роутером). В итоге он добирается до роутера и тут опять куда пойдет пакет кому из двух пользователей? Как это реализовано в Skype может кто знает, там же еще сложнее через p2p, но хотя бы просто понять с сервером.

Есть идея в плане если узнать какой ip и порт устанавливает Nat провайдера и сервер посылал бы туда ответ это бы решило проблему определения, когда запрос дойдет до провайдера, но как решить вопрос когда дойдет вопрос до роутера вообще ума не приложу, не писать же гайд юзеру о пробросе портов. спасибо

Comment: что то у Вас все смешалось в  тексте. То сервер куда то подключается, то клиент ждет подключений. Обычно есть сервер, который имеет реальный ip и все к нему подключаются. В этом случае проблем нет.

Если же хочется сделать p2p соединения, то смотртите в сторону STUN.

Comment: То есть я правильно вас понял что клиент постоянно отправляет запросы на сервер а сервер присылает в ответ либо что ничего не произошло либо какое то событие!?

Comment: И еще вопрос. если все таки потом решу преобразовать чат в p2p, тогда для двух серых ip надо использовать связующий сервер, который будет узнавать свой внешний ip и порт и передавать его на сервер а второй клиент получает эти данные и подключается в этот открытый канал!?а роутер сам поймет что это ответ с Nat на посланный ранее запрос!?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NAT** - Network Address Translation - Преобразование сетевых адресов. Под этим термином в принципе понимают любое преобразование как адреса отправителя так и адреса назначения. На бытовом уровне, т.е. в обычных маршрутизаторах под NAT подразумевается одна из его разновидностей, которая обеспечивает соединения нескольких клиентов с внутренними адресами с внешним миром, используя при этом один общий IP-адрес.

Достигается это следующим образом: Пусть клиенты A и B одновременно хотят связаться с сервером S. Они открывают сокет, на который их ОС назначает временный номер порта. Клиент A шлет запрос: `TCP 192.168.0.100:4001 -> 198.51.100.1:80`, клиент B: `TCP 192.168.0.101:4001 -> 198.51.100.1:80`. Роутер видя эти пакеты меняет адрес отправителя в пакетах на свой внешний и при этом он так же меняет и номер порта отправителя, в интернет с роутера уходят следующие пакеты: `203.0.113.23:31001 -> 198.51.100.1:80 SYN` и `203.0.113.23:31010 -> 198.51.100.1:80`. Плюс к этому роутер запоминает в своей таблице связки `31001 это 192.168.0.100:4001` и `31010 это 192.168.0.101:4001`. На основе запомненных связок, когда сервер 198.51.100.1 пришлет ответные пакеты, адресованные на порты 31001 и 31010 роутер по этому номеру порта поймет какому клиенту отдать ответный трафик. Если по данной связке ip-портов какое то время не проходит никакой трафик роутер выбросит запись из своей таблицы. Так же он выбросит запись если увидит проходящий TCP пакет означающий конец соединения (FIN). Время таймаута для TCP обычно велико, для UDP меньше. Например, в стандартно настроенном linux таймаут для полностью установленного TCP-соединения 120 часов, а для UDP - 30 секунд

Исходя из этого для работы с сервером клиент может открыть обычное TCP соединение и ни о чем особо более не заботится. Работу по поддержанию соединения в открытом состоянии, в том числе что бы роутеры не выбросили его из таблиц трансляции берет на себя ОС, в том числе время от времени посылая пакеты keep alive, сообщая что соединение все еще есть. Для UDP эту работу должно производить само приложение. Т.е. клиент, если долгое время не идет никакого полезного обмена трафиком должен посылать пакеты "я жив". В остальное время клиент может спокойно ожидать на сокете входящих сообщений с сервера, ежесекундный обмен трафиком ни к чему. Для работы с сервером не следует использовать сокеты открываемые на прослушку, потому как NAT о них просто не узнает и не пришлет трафик.

Для работы клиентов друг с другом на прямую используется резервирование портов у роутера по протоколу [UPnP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) и/или выяснение своих портов по [STUN](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN). Но ни тот ни другой механизм не может гарантировать работоспособность конкретного клиента. UPnP обычно понимают только домашние маршрутизаторы. Так же у провайдера NAT может работать в жестком режиме и контролировать, что трафик на запомненный в таблице трансляции порт приходит именно от того IP кому был послан изначальный запрос, в таком случае STUN так же не поможет. Поэтому для работы p2p оба клиента, используя взаимодействие с сервером, должны определить свои возможности и исходя из этого принимать решение кто, к кому и в какой последовательности должен подключатся.