# Пересылка пакетов без открытия портов через роутер

Tags: java, tcp, udp, nat

У меня написан сетевой код который пересылает по заданным портам.
Если у человека стоит роутер ему нужно открывать порты.
Если в локальной сети находятся два компьютера то роутер может перенаправлять пакеты только одному.

Но я могу звонить по skype компьютерам из своей локальной сети.
В сетевых играх типа warcraft и lineage порты открывать ненужно 
и компьютеры в локальной сети работают нормально.

Вопрос:
1. Как сделана сетевая часть в подобных приложениях?
2. Есть ли способ автоматически определить локальный ip адрес компьютера который находится за роутером и послать ему пакеты без предварительного открытия портов на роутере.

Нашел такую вещь 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: Автоматический проброс портов через UPnP

Comment: Человек должен сам сначала установить соединение с сервером из-за NAT.

Comment: У тебя клиент и сервер за NAT?

Comment: в большинстве игр используются внешние сервера с фиксированным айпишником (это никак не отменяет вопрос, просто уточняю)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496346/

Comment: 1. Есть сервер с открытыми портами

Если на клиенте отрыть порты и постучать то все работает

Если у клиента стоит роутер то нужно открыть порты на роутере (как сделать это автоматически?)

Если компьютеры находятся в одной локальной сети и подключены при помощи роутера то роутер может делать редирект только на один компьютер

Comment: Да этот вопрос.

Comment: Что означает "роутер может делать редирект только на один компьютер?". Если под "открыть порты" и "редирект" вы имеете в виду функциональность "Port Forwarding", то кто вам мешает заставить роутер форвардить порт 123 на локальный компьютер A, а порт 456 на на локальный компьютер B? Вот уже получился "редирект" на два разных компьютера.

Comment: У меня клиент серверный фреймворк по типу скайпа.

На сервер открыты 2 порта один для входящих другой для исходящих

Сервер жде что к неу постучатся на порт 8086.
А отвечает на порт  8092.

Все работает если стучится один компьютер.

Если стоит роутер то нужно пробрасывать порты.

Если за роутером два компьютера:

Роутер делает forvarding только на один.

Comment: @Иван Александров: Так в том то и дело, что *слушать* сервер может на фиксированном порту (ваш 8086), а вот *отвечать* сервер должен уметь на *любой* порт. На какой порт надо слать ответ - это выбирает клиент и сообщает об этом серверу при изначальной установке соединения. То есть для каждого активного клиента сервер должен хранить не просто адрес, но и номер порта.

Comment: @AnT: там это есть просто не будешь же для каждого клиента за роутером открывать свой порт, неужели нет способа посылать пакеты на машину с определенным локальным ip?

Comment: @Иван Александров: Вся идея NAT заключается в том, что внешний мир не должен знать никаких локальных IP. И да, именно так работает NAT роутер в режиме "overloading", т.е. когда локальная сеть видна внешнему миру через один-единственный IP адрес - адрес роутера. Для каждого исходящего соединения роутером заводится свой порт (и прописывется роутером во все исходящие пакеты этого соединения). На этот порт будут приходить ответы. Роутер по номеру порта, на который пришел ответный пакет, определяет на какой компьютер (*и какой порт*) внутри  LAN надо зафорвардить этот ответный пакет.

Comment: Так формируется исходящее соединение, то есть соединение инициированное компьютером из LAN. Манипуляции с портами автоматически выполняет роутер. Если же компьютер в LAN должен просто пассивно сидеть и слушать какой-то из своих портов, то перенаправить входящие извне пакеты на этот порт локального компьютера можно только путем ручного задания порт-форвардинга в роутере. И если таких слушающих компьютеров в LAN несколько, то каждому придется выделить отдельный внешний порт в роутере.

Comment: @AnT: Мне нужно постоянно слушать. нашел вот такой mapper как думаете стоит использовать http://bitletorg.github.io/weupnp/

Comment: @Иван Александров: Ну вы, помнится, спрашивали про Скайп. Скайп-клиент не является полностью пассивным слушателем. А именно: при выходе в онлайн клиент активно устанавливает соединение с сервером. То есть соединение исходит от клиента, изнутри LAN и поддерживается открытым все время, пока клиент находится в онлайне. Вот в момент установки соединения NAT роутер и назначает каждому такому соединению свой порт. То есть каждый скайп-клиент в LAN получает ответы на свой внешний порт роутера. Для работы скайп-клинета не надо вручную настраивать форвардинг портов на роутере и не нужен uPnP.

Comment: @AnT: тогда если использовать UPnP библиотеку и открывать каждому локальному компьютеру свой порт. А на сервере записывать какие порты открыты на определенном компьютере?

Comment: В warcraft для игры открывать порт **нужно** если вы - хост.