# Как можно узнать адрес в корпоративной сети

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, ip, tcp-ip

Как можно узнать внешний айпи адрес и порт моего компьютера который находится внутри корпоративной сети, узнал айпи адрес на сайте http://myip.ru, но ведь это один адрес на все компьютеры в корпоративной сети, как из вне могут достучаться до моего локального компьютера.
Развернул локальный вэб сервер с портом 88, но как можно достучаться до него из вне.

Comment: Есть только один путь: уволить текущего сисадмина и нанять раздолбая, который пробросит порт 88 на ваш компьютер. После чего увольняться уже вдвоём.

Comment: @pinktux а если разверну на 80 порту?

Comment: NAT (от англ. Network Address Translation — «преобразование сетевых адресов») — это механизм в сетях TCP/IP, позволяющий преобразовывать IP-адреса транзитных пакетов.

Comment: Да без разницы. На своём личном компьютере ты можешь делать что угодно. В корпоративной сети это грубейшее нарушение политики безопасности, за которое нужно отрывать разные органы.

Comment: @pinktux Ну это где как, есть компании с 5 человек и корпоративная сеть, сделано только ради локалки, есть компании с 10 подсетями, где чтобы достучаться до 10-й подсети нужно пройти все 9 подсеток, там как раз все и хранится, вопрос то не в этом

Comment: @didex что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ну, дело ваше. Но кранты вашей сети, если её админы ничего не знают про проброс портов или NAT...

Comment: @pinktux мы всей компанией с админами вместе собрались и решили задать вопрос здесь.

Comment: Короче, раз у вас один внешний Ip, то из вне добраться до вашего компьютера невозможно. Необходимо явно пробрасывать порт на вашем внешнем маршрутизаторе, который выполняет сборку вас в один IP

Comment: подробнее о том как работает NAT: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496419/194569 что бы было понятно, почему вы можете добраться наружу, а  снаружи до вас нельзя

Comment: @mike понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)** (от англ. *Network Address Translation* — «преобразование сетевых адресов») — это механизм в сетях TCP/IP, позволяющий преобразовывать IP-адреса транзитных пакетов.

Преобразование адреса методом **NAT** может производиться почти любым маршрутизирующим устройством — маршрутизатором, сервером доступа, межсетевым экраном.

Принимая пакет от локального компьютера, роутер смотрит на IP-адрес назначения. Если это локальный адрес, то пакет пересылается другому локальному компьютеру. Если нет, то пакет надо переслать наружу в интернет. Но ведь обратным адресом в пакете указан локальный адрес компьютера, который из интернета будет недоступен. Поэтому роутер «на лету» транслирует (подменяет) обратный IP-адрес пакета на свой внешний (видимый из интернета) IP-адрес и меняет номер порта (чтобы различать ответные пакеты, адресованные разным локальным компьютерам).

Теперь Вам осталось найти то, что у вас раздает интернет и то, что в нем отвечает за NAT (Port forwarding, переадресация портов, и тд). И создать правило. Например у меня для апача -

> ```
>  IP-адрес источника: 192.168.1.1   
>   Диапазон портов: 2000    
>     Локальный IP-адрес: 192.168.1.12   
>     Локальный  порт: 8080  
>     Протокол:  TCP/UDP
> ```

Когда на роутер (192.168.1.1) и порт 2000 придет пакет из интернета, он автоматически перенаправится на ip 192.168.1.12 и 8080 порт локальной сети

Comment: Вот этого я не понимал, спасибо

Comment: А как роутер справляется, портов всего 65000, пользователей по много запросов в большой сети много?

Answer (score 1):

1) если стоит обычный роутер - зайти на него и в настройках Интернет указать переаресацию портов. При этом внешний адрес останется тем же, который получен по myip.ru

В примере порт 3389 компьютера с локальным адресом 192.168.1.219 виден снаружи на порту 4444 для доступа по rdp.
[image: в примере порт 3389 компьютера с локальным адресом 192.168.1.219 виден снаружи на порту 4444 для доступа по rdp]
Переадресация портов позволяет удаленным компьютерам подключаться к конкретному компьютеру локальной сети (LAN). При этом, если порт 88 не используется организацией - можно его не менять.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать свой сайт доступным в сети тор. Краткая инструкция:

1.Установить браузер тор.

2.В папке куда установлен tor-бразуер находим файл torrc и добавляем туда строки:

```
HiddenServiceDir C:\<путь-к-пустой-папке>
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:88
```

3. Запускаем/Перезапускаем браузер тор. Если все сделано правильно, в папке C:\<путь-к-пустой-папке> будут два файла hostname и private_key

Ваш веб-серер доступен в сети тор по адресу, который записан в файле hostname.

Comment: Спасибо, идея хорошая, но боюсь меня уволят, когда безопасники узнают об этом), обращусь к админам чтобы настроили маршрутизацию

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы узнать свой ip-адрес с локальной (или корпоративной) сети, достаточно в командной строке выполнить команду `ipconfig`.
2. Чтобы обращаться из корпоративной сети к сайту, развёрнутому на одном из компов, ip-адрес знать не надо, достаточно доменного имени (возможно, полного доменного имени).
3. Не забудь настроить firewall, чтобы он разрешал такие подключения.